# What kind of mount does the Cowboystudio NPT-04 receiver have?

Tags: wireless-triggers

I nearly bought a set of Phottix Aster trigger+receivers, but at the last minute stopped when I discovered that the receivers don't mount via a standard flash shoe. Instead they require a camera/tripod mount. Very weird. The guy at the photo shop said that was common. But to me, that makes everything more expensive: need to get adapters for each stand, etc.

I'm wondering if the NPT-04's do this as well, or not. It *seems* like they have both, actually: a standard flash mount plus a threaded hole for a camera tripod. Very nice - especially considering they're 1/3 the price of the Phottix.

But *I'm not sure*, because I can't find an actual picture of the underside of an NPT-04 receiver. Can someone confirm exactly how these mount?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the trigger and the receiver use standard hot shoe mounts. I mount it on a hot shoe to lightstand adapter with the flash on top.

I actually never noticed the 1/4" threaded hole at the bottom!